# Interpretation - after transforming slope to elasticity

Tags: elasticity

Basically, my question is, after I transform the slope into elasticity by using the standard formula

[image]

How do I interpret the number I get?

Say, I got -0.21. Should I interpret it as -0.21%, or -20% ?  I believe it is -0.21%.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the formula as $$\varepsilon=\frac{100\cdot\frac{\Delta \bar y}{\bar y}}{100 \cdot \frac{\Delta \bar x}{\bar x}}=\frac{-0.21\%}{1\%}$$

This hopefully makes things clearer. The top is percentage change in expected $y$, while the bottom is the percentage change in $x$.

In other words, -0.21 means that for a 1% increase in $x$, the expected value of $y$ falls by $0.21$%. This is inelastic since it it less than 1 in absolute value.

You can also say that for 10% bump in $x$, expected $y$ falls by 2.1%.

Comment: @YunqingMa If this helped, please select it as the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left.

Comment: Sorry for the late click!